# Restore bginfo wallpaper after RDP disconnect and reconnect

Tags: remote-desktop, windows

I often end my RDP session by closing the window (*without* logging off). When I reconnect, the system is exactly the way it was before I disconnected (i.e. same windows are open, etc...)

Except: The [bginfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx) wallpaper overlay has disappeared. I can restore the wallpaper by manually running bginfo or logging off and back on.

**How do I make the wallpaper restore itself when reconnecting (or persist between connections) to an existing RDP session?**

Comment: Check your RDP settings.  Are you sure you don't have your client set to mess around with the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding BGinfo as a program to run on connection in the settings of your RDP client.  RDP > Options > Programs tab.

[image: RDP client programs tab]

I also had to check "Desktop background" on the Experience tab for this to work consistently.

[image: RDP client experience tab]

Answer (score 0):

Because bginfo isn't a process that continues to run, you are probably going to be out of luck.  As per it's notes, "BGInfo simply writes a new desktop bitmap and exits".  It has no way to tell if the desktop needs refreshing, and it does not modify your profile's background image settings in order to allow Windows to re-load it from disk & display it properly.

You might be better off using one of the many desktop widgets/gadgets that exist out there.  I particularly like [rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/cms/) for displaying system stats.

Answer (score -1):

Try [BGINFO4X](http://bginfo4x.sourceforge.net). It has all the features you need, and much more.